# Occasionally floor around toilet is very very wet. Why?

Tags: toilet, leaks

A couple of times per week the bathroom floor will be flooded from the toilet. Not sure why since I'm not there when it happens. Can flush the toilet over and over again and everything seems fine. Help.

Comment: If you have a second toilet, then turn off the water on the one that has a problem and flush it to get most of the water out. Then wait a few days and see if the problem is still happening. Also watch the water level inside the toilet to see if it changes at all. This will help you track down where the problem is. If you still experience the problem and the toilet isn't leaking water, then you know that it isn't the toilet.

Comment: Got boys in the house?

Answer (score 2):

it is possible that the wax ring is damaged, when another appliance like a washing machine drains the water backs up and causes the water on the floor. If this is the case it will probably get worse and your lines will need to be cleaned tree roots cause this very often in older homes.

Comment: Plus one: this is indicative of a second problem downstream, assuming it isn't pilot error.

Answer (score 0):

**1. It can be a leak from other pipe than toilet's.**

**2. Water penetrating floor material needs time to make this visible.**

If You happen to have other drain pipe, like from a sink or a bathtub, it may be that's the problem. You can try to do the following:

- flush a toilet 3 times, wait 2 hours, observe
- use sink for a considerable time, wait 2 hours, observe
- (other sources, same thing)

Apart of that, even if water may be leaking from other pipe, the area around the toilet may be a depression, so no matter what pipe is leaking, it can still be staying in that place.

Also, if there is some pipe from the storey above, it can make same effect (it the leakage is below floor surface and area around the toilet is lower than the rest).

Answer (score 0):

The probable answer is the wax ring is leaking. Another possibility i've encountered is a tank fill valve hose is not positioned properly and the water hits the top of tank and runs down. Easily checked by lifting tank lid and flushing toilet to observe if there is water splashing where it should not be. Good luck.